# How to avoid lots of if else conditions with some conditions inside if else

Tags: java, spring-boot, optimization

I am trying to avoid if else conditions can you guys please help me?

```
if (getFromDate() != null && getToDate() != null && getBranchId() != null && getServiceGroupId() != null) {

        return something;

    } else if (getFromDate() != null && getToDate() != null && getBranchId() != null && getServiceGroupId() == null) {

        return something;

    } else if (getFromDate() != null && getToDate() != null && getServiceGroupId() != null && getBranchId() == null) {

        return something;

    } else if (getServiceGroupId() != null && getBranchId() != null && getFromDate() == null && getToDate() == null) {

        return something;

    } else if (getServiceGroupId() == null && getBranchId() == null && getFromDate() != null && getToDate() != null) {

        return something;
    } else if (getFromDate() == null && getToDate() == null && getBranchId() == null && getServiceGroupId() != null) {

        return something;
    } else if (getFromDate() == null && getToDate() == null && getBranchId() != null && getServiceGroupId() == null) {

        return something;

    } else {
        return something;
    }
```

Comment: You ask as if we know the logic behind your `if`s and `else`s... You could first start by explaining what you are trying to achieve, then we may be able to help you

Comment: maybe he wants to do some sql search based on conditinal where clauses?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `if ... else`?

Comment: <pedantic>there is little reason, the result is always 'something'</pedantic> more seriously: clever reordering/grouping can help a lot, you can hide selection using method overloads, or convert if/then/else into a table lookup compute, but at the heart of it, it's still an if..else

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Stream.allMatch(x -> x == null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) to check for mutiple `null` values from different or similar types. Declare `Stream` variables (or an array) using [`Stream.of(T... values)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-).

It is best declared on some function `boolean foo(T... varargs)`.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following pattern in your code:

You have a group of boolean conditions (some value being null vs. not null) and want to return different values based on specific true/false combinations of these conditions.

If you encounter this pattern at multiple places, it might be worth to introduce a supporting class. Let's call it `MultiBoolean`, so you can write:

```
MultiBoolean nullCombinations = new MultiBoolean(
    getFromDate() == null,
    getToDate() == null,
    getBranchId() == null,
    getServiceGroupId() == null);
if (nullCombinations.matches(false, false, false, false) {
    return something;
} else if (nullCombinations.matches(false, false, false, true) {
    return something;
} else if (...) {
    // and so on
```

The class might roughly look like:

```
public class MultiBoolean {
    private boolean[] conditions;
    public MultiBoolean(boolean... conditions) {
        this.conditions = conditions;
    }
    public boolean matches(boolean... pattern) {
        return Arrays.equals(conditions, pattern);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test it.